# CSS Separator issue, markup/syntax help needed

Tags: css, separator

I am building my first template so im sure this is due to incorrect markup of some sort.

I have been trying to get two image seperators to display between 3 boxes on my homepage. One appears to be displaying. However something isnt right, i cant get the first seperator to appear.

I have tried creating a div with a background image and adding it into the index.php and have tried adding as an image (how the seccond one is working).

Could anyone shed some light onto whats going on?

My CSS can be found here; http://www.adamtoms.co.uk/templates/mk1/css/system.css and the website is http://adamtoms.co.uk

Here is where I am trying to palce the div/img;

```
    <?php if ($this->countModules( 'left or right or midmid' )) : ?>    
<div id="leftrightmain">
        <div id="midleft">  
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="left" />
        </div>      
        <div id="midmid">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="midmid" />
        </div>
        <img id="sep" src="/templates/mk1/images/sep.png">
        <div id="midright">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="right" />
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Many thanks,
Adam

Comment: Not sure I understand exactly whats going on here.  With your structure above, if you want two dividers, simply copy the existing image code, and paste it after the closing div tag for #midleft

Comment: that doesnt work, it shifts the other two boxes down and the separator isnt displayed.

Comment: One moment for a solution, I understand whats going on now.

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net of your problem.

Comment: We cannot tap into your php code, and your css is one huge file. Please consider building a [reduced test-case](http://css-tricks.com/reduced-test-cases/), containing only the relevant bits of your code. You'll be more likely to get a solution.

Comment: im not sure how I would do that. I am running joomla so cant just copy the code. I can give it ago may take me a while. Or i could upload my index.php?

Comment: Don't sweat it @atoms I posted a solution for you.  You were simply applying your css semi-incorrectly in a way.

Comment: ok i think this should help;
http://jsfiddle.net/eSJgU/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your current structure, you need to simply do something like this:

First, remove the HTML image you added.

```
<?php if ($this->countModules( 'left or right or midmid' )) : ?>    
<div id="leftrightmain">
        <div id="midleft class="sepp">  
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="left" />
        </div>
        <div id="midmid class="sepp">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="midmid" />
        </div>
        <div id="midright">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="right" />
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I have added a class to your midleft and midmid divs.  The class is `.sepp`

In your CSS, you need to change this line:

```
#sepp {
    background-image: url("../images/sep.png")
}
```

To...

```
.sepp {
    background-image: url("../images/sep.png");
    background-position: 50% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

The above will apply the CSS class styles for `.sepp` to your left and middle divs.  The css tells the background image to not repeat and to be positioned at 50% on the vertical (center) and 100% from the left (right justified).

**EDIT:**

Quite a few changes...  We need to swap the styling around, make the sepp div the container.

```
<?php if ($this->countModules( 'left or right or midmid' )) : ?>    
<div id="leftrightmain">
        <div class="sepp">
            <div id="midleft">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="left" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sepp">
            <div id="midmid">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="midmid" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sepp last">
            <div id="midright">
               <jdoc:include type="modules" name="right" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And the CSS:

```
.sepp {
    width: 25%;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 0 1%;
    margin: 0px -1% 0px 7%;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url("../images/sep.png");
    background-position: 50% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 1px 100%;
}
```

And on the 3 ID's midleft midmid midright, remove margin and padding, and make with 100%.

```
#midleft {
min-height: 100%;
float: left;
width: 100%;
/* -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    position: relative;
    border: 0px 3px 3px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgb(153, 153, 153); */
position:relative;
background-image:url("../images/bksa.png");
background-size:75px 75px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: top center;
display:block;
}
```

Get this done then comment and let me know, there will be more that needs to happen.

Comment: many thanks Michael,this makes alot more sense that what ive been attempting. Ive applied it as suggested but its not showing the seperator.. Know its something stupid ive missed can you see it? http://www.adamtoms.co.uk/

Comment: Ah, it's quite simple.  There is another background image that's overwriting it, some further modification of the HTML above is needed.  hold on, and see my edit in a few minutes.

Comment: @atoms Let me know if that does not work.  It should get us close.  If it does not there is one last way that will definitely work but would require a fairly large edit to the CSS.

Comment: it doenst appear to have worked Michael, take a look at my site i have applied the changes,
thanks for your help with this as well!

Comment: I see it, as I said it got us close.  We need some further modification now.  Another edit soon, I will replace the code that is in the current edit.

Comment: @atoms I made a chatroom but just realized you can't join without 20rep.  Do you have Skype?

Comment: I dont have access to the chat sorry @Michael (blocked in my office) is there any alternative, could do facebook?
Ive made the changes as set out in your edit, looks like it needs an inline setting or something to that effect?

Comment: Change the width of .sepp to 25% - I have skype if that's doable.  Or GMAIL chat.

Comment: Sent, facebook friend invite.  I'd suggest you delete ur profile above^^ ;)